# How to use a variable from an input in a jquery validation witht his value being updated when typing?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate a hostname/ip in jquery by sending an AJAX request. The ip should come from the input field I validate.

```
rules: {
    ip: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: 'http://' + ip + ':8888/api/foo',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
```

How can I pass the input variable to the rule? Is it possible at all?

Edit: This seems important but I need the value to be updated when typing it

Comment: then you can use onblur when typing is complete for that input and focus moved to other field or onKeyup kind of events for doing the thing while typing

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use $('input').val() and pass it to your rule

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
url: 'http://' + $('#input').val() + ':8888/api/foo',
```

In place of the ip variable.

Comment: That was working for how i formulated my question but i realized i forgot to precise it needs to be updated when typing. I edited the question

Comment: If it needs to be updated while typing, use an event listner to listen to each key press in the input box.